# check all images loaded after .ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to know when all images are loaded from appended html source to perform another function. How can I check that?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('a.load-more').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $(this).attr('href'),
        data: {
            page: last_id
        },
        dataType: "script",

        success: function () {
            $('.load-more').show();
        }
    });
  });
});
```

I'm appending html source like this:

```
$('.container').append('<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => @items)) %>');
```

It gives html source successfully, but I can't find out when all images from that source is loaded

.container updates every time link is clicked `<a href="/items" class="load-more">Load more</a>`

and the .container source looks like this:

```
<ul class="container">
  <%= render @items %>
</ul>
```

Comment: When does the `append()` happen? It appears unrelated to the AJAX call you're making.

Comment: it happens when the link is clicked. It will be repeated multiple times

Comment: What does? The AJAX call, or the append? How does the append relate to the AJAX call? Seeing a more complete example of your code would help a lot here.

Comment: Do you need to support IE8?

Comment: @A.Wolff thanks! after I will get it working elsewhere :)

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I have updated. Is it enought? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On all browsers supporting event capturing phase, you can capture onload event for all new added images:

```
document.addEventListener(
    'load',
    function(event){
        var elm = event.target;
        if( elm.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'img' && $(elm).closest('.container').length && !$(elm).hasClass('loaded')){ // or any other filtering condition
            console.log('image loaded');
            $(elm).addClass('loaded');
            if($('.container img.loaded').length === $('.container img').length) {          
                // do some stuff
                console.log("All images loaded!")
            }
        }
    },
    true // Capture event
);
```

To support e.g IE8 which doesn't handle capturing phase, you should set onload event to specific images once they are added in the DOM, setting it in `script` onload event.

Comment: should I check every image on appended html source? It would be hundreads of them...

Comment: onload event would be captured for any image. I'm not sure to understand your questions?  EDIT: ok i see what you mean `I need to know when all images are loaded from appended html`  So ya, you should count all images in appended HTML and set a counter to check once all images are loaded

Comment: I think you are genius! Thank you! going to implement :)

Comment: I got "All images loaded!" in my localhost console, but can't get on production server. Do you know why? Here is production sample - http://tobuleti.lt/ - click on "Rodyti daugiau"

Comment: Sometimes it works, but sometimes refreshing page it doesn't.. Interesting!

Comment: Could be because onload event beeing fired before you bind it. Try setting this snippet before any DOM element is parsed, meaning setting it from HEAD section and without wrapping it on any other hanlder, e.g document ready or window onload